# Uncaught TypeError in call to jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a plugin using jQuery to page a table. Initially, my code looks like this:

```
(function($) {
$.paginate = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.paginate.defaults, options);

};

$.paginate.defaults = {
    pageSize: 10,
    nextText: 'Next',
    prevText: 'Prev',
    firstText: '<<'
    lastText: '>>'
}

})(jQuery);
```

And the call to the plugin like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".table").paginate({
            pageSize: 10
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, the paginate function is not being found by jQuery. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are messing up with use of `$.fn`

The plugin method needs to be assigned to `$.fn` in order to use `$(selector).myPlugin()`

```
$.fn.paginate = function(options) {...
```

Then you have a mismatch between

```
 $.paginate.defaults
```

And

```
$.extend({}, $.fn.paginate.defaults
            // ^^ fn here but not above
```

Comment: Same problem this way. I tried to change the form of the call, but it did not work, too:

`$(function() {
       $('tabela').paginate({
           pageSize: 4
       });
   });`

Comment: Any errors in console? note that `'tabela'` is invalid selector. There are lots of resources on web about how to create plugins and even tools to generate base plugin code

Comment: That's it. I modified the selector and added a "," after the `firstText` field and it worked. Strange that the browser did not show syntax error previously. After these adjustments, it worked. Thank you.